# Make MySQL 5.5.24 Accept Queries Designed For 4.1.22

Tags: mysql, join, version, compatibility

We just migrated one of our databases from a 4.1.22 server to a 5.5.24 server. It's giving an error for this query:

```
... FROM node n INNER JOIN node_access na ON na.nid = n.nid INNER JOIN event e USING (nid)..
```

.

And the error is:

```
ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'nid' in from clause is ambiguous
```

It would be difficult to change the queries at the moment. We are wondering if it's possible to make MySQL 5.5.24 to simulate 4.1.22 to accept that query. We already looked into sql_mode and it did not seem to be the thing we are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If feasible do query rewriting by changing USING to "ON" with column values. 
However if query rewriting is not an option I don't think one can change the SQL standard to an older one SQL:99 (used by MYSQL 4).

Answer (score 0):

**The simple answer:** it is not possible.

You could try adding a proxy in between to rewrite the query, but the best solution would be to change the query in the application.